# Trying to update Twitter status with request.js

Tags: node.js, twitter

This returns a "Bad Authentication Data" error

```
  request.post({
    url: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json",
    oauth: {
      consumer_key: auth.twitter.consumerKey,
      consumer_secret: auth.twitter.consumerSecret,
      access_token_key: this.authToken,
      access_token_secret: this.authSecret
    },
    params: {
      status: "Check this out!!"
    }
  }, function(err, response, body) {
    return console.log(err, body); // null '{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}'
  });
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are preventing this from running:

`access_token_key` should be `token`, and `access_token_secret` should be `token_secret`

Sending POST data works a bit differently with the request module. Try something like this

```
var r = request.post({url:url, oauth:params}, function(err, resp, body) {
    res.end("Tweet sent successfully");
});

var form = r.form();
form.append("status", "Check this out!!");
```